# how to archive msmq messages?

Tags: .net, msmq

I have a bunch of messages in one of the queues from an old date. I would like to take a backup before purging them. Any thoughts?

Schar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move them to a file and back it up. It can be done with a tool like [QueueExplorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/?c=1&gclid=CPuj9eqhtp4CFQQ9Zgod0xuBlA) (cheap but not free) or write something like that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I researched a bit more and found the following options:
1. The command line utility: mqbkup [-b][-r] [dest directory]
This stops MSMQ service and backs up every queue on that machine.   

2. Writing or using a tool like Queue explorer. 

I guess this is the best option. 

-Sri

Comment: To clarify : We have to write a tool or get one to move messages from one queue to another or save them.